# How do I download and not pay another 16 bucks?

Tags: installation, downloads, donation

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 (64 b) and donated my 16 bucks, and I cannot find it on my computer anywhere.

Comment: You don't need to pay money to be able to use Ubuntu. It's a free choice...

Comment: Look in the Downloads folder.

Comment: @Alvar but doesn't it feel so much better that way? :)

Comment: You can download it again, this time choosing for free. And make sure you save it in _your desired_ location. 
Witch OS (Operating System) & Browser did you use to download your copy of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Gracchus No, the point of Ubuntu is that you can make it better by contributing to the community not to pay money to the company behind the software. I haven't donated any money to Ubuntu, but I have contributed to the community, and how much money is that worth?

Answer (score 2):

By default there is this window with 2 $ on every part u can donate on.
i thought the costs are 16 dollar as well but look at my screenshot, you just missed the text on the left :)

[image: ITS FREE]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also download Ubuntu as a Torrent, check the Download - Desktop tab in the Ubuntu website. As has been pointed out, the donation is voluntary, you could conceivably re-download, and just select skip when it comes to ask for the donation